# Flask-WTForms not passing data when submitted. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm new to Python and the Flask framework and I can't figure out how to pass data to a form.  I keep getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' when I submit the form.

I'm able to pass the object (invoice1) from the view to the template and display the object properties. (invoice.id) but I can't pass the object to the Form.

```
@app.route('/invoice/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def addItem():
    invoice2 = request.args.get('invoice_id', type=int)
    invoice1 = Invoice.query.filter_by(id=invoice2).first()
    form = ItemForm(obj=invoice1)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newItem = Item(
            invoice = invoice1,
            quantity = form.quantity.data,
            category = form.category.data,
            brand = form.brand.data,
            model = form.model.data,
            serialNumber = form.serialNumber.data,
            condition = form.condition.data,
            notes = form.notes.data,
            cost = form.cost.data
            )
        db.session.add(newItem)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('invoice'))
    return render_template('invoice/addItems.html', form=form, invoice1=invoice1)
```

form.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import validators, IntegerField, StringField, TextAreaField, HiddenField
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from item.models import Category, Brand


class BrandForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Enter Brand', [validators.Required(), validators.Length(max=80)])

class CategoryForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Enter Category', [validators.Required(), validators.Length(max=80)])

def categories():
    return Category.query.order_by(Category.name).all()

def brands():
    return Brand.query.order_by(Brand.name).all()

class ItemForm(Form):
    #invoice = IntegerField('Invoice Number')
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity', [validators.Required()])
    category = QuerySelectField('Category', [validators.Required()], query_factory=categories, allow_blank=True, blank_text=u'-- please choose --')
    brand = QuerySelectField('Brand', [validators.Required()], query_factory=brands, allow_blank=True, blank_text=u'-- please choose --')
    model = StringField('Model')
    serialNumber = StringField('Serial Number')
    condition = StringField('Condition')
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes')
    cost = IntegerField('Cost', default=0)
```

addItems.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Invoice{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

        <h3>Add Items to Invoice</h3>

        {{ invoice1.id }}

        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('addItem') }}" role="form">


            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}


            {{ render_field(form.quantity, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.category, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.brand, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.model, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.serialNumber, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.condition, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.notes, class ='form-control') }}
            {{ render_field(form.cost, class ='form-control') }}


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Item</button>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I can successfully save records to the DB via the shell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

- Izzy

Comment: `invoice1 = Invoice.query.filter_by(id=invoice2).first()` what value does it returns?

Comment: It is returning an instance of Invoice object. I am able to return the value of invoice1.id.